# Symlinks created but not "there" SSH

Tags: debian, ssh, directory, symlink

I am creating Symlinks for Magento purposes but for some reason something is going wrong. 
I created the symlinks using PuTTy SSH.
So I did this:
`cd /home/user/domains/newwebsite/public_html/` 
`ln -s /home/user/domains/oldwebsite/public_html/app/ app` 
So this is supposed to create a "shortcut" towards the `app` directory on the old website, right?
Well, it did, kind of. If I do `dir` it shows the directory. But when I look at it on FileZilla, it shows nothing.
Also, going to the `app` directory, it perfectly shows the files and directories it should contain.
When I create the folder `app` using FileZilla, I'm unable to open it. And when I delete the `app` folder, it is also gone using the `dir` command.
Changing names of files using FileZilla also changes it when using `dir`.
I have been doing this for a couple of other websites and it works fine.

Using Debian 8.
[image: FileZilla]
[image: SSH]

```
cd app
```

[image: SSH2] 
Might be that FileZilla is not reliable but the website doesn't show anything so there must be something different going on.

Comment: Server software often has default flags to the effect of "never follow symlinks" so you cannot by accident reveal files outside of `public_html` (like password files), I'd guess that's what you are running into.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, Hmm I read about that. I was kind of expecting it to follow symlinks as it did with other users. But I am beginning to doubt it. I will ask my server management guy if this might be the case. Thanks!